# Which gaming platform should be used?

Tags: c#, xna, directx, monodevelop, monogame

I am individual game developer and make games for fun. I was using xna lately to create small game.

Just want to know which gaming platform is good for individual developer. As XNA is no more supported by microsoft. MonoXNA does not provide such power of 3d. Unity license is very expensive.

Once we spent too much time on a game, we would love to port it over different platform? That too I would like to keep in mind while selecting any framework?

Should C# developer learn DirectX library for gaming?

Where is the industry moving in terms of game programming?

Thanks

Comment: Unity is available for free, if your annual revenue is below 100,000 $.

Comment: I am individual developer not a company.

Comment: That does not matter, but if you use Unity for non-commercial purposes it's free anyway.

Comment: Great. But I would like to make some money from my hard work by publishing my apps to app store ( Free or Paid)

Comment: Then my first comment applies.

Comment: read this article guys nice for C# game developers : http://gamasutra.com/blogs/PedroGuida/20140114/208519/So_XNA_is_dead_now_what.php

Answer (score 3):

I'd still recommend MonoGame. It's open source, crossplatform. 3D support may improve over time. If you really want to do serious 3D stuff, I'd use an engine for that, like Unreal or Source. Otherwise It's gonna be too much work for a single programmer.

Here are some useful links. I can't really point to a specific engine, because that highly depends on the type of game you want to create. But I will list some great and popular (and maybe too powerful for a single programmer) anyway, mostly used for FPS games.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines
- http://source.valvesoftware.com/
- http://www.unrealengine.com/en/udk/
- http://mycryengine.com/

But again it really depends on what you want.

Comment: Simple 2d game will not become so popular and depends totally on innovative graphics. Unreal and Source are cross platform gaming engine or just for C# guys?

Comment: I disagree that 2D games can't be popular. Plenty of counter examples. Crappy 3D games won't be popular. For serious 3D stuff, use a grownup engine.

Comment: I does not mean that 2d games are not useful. Can you provide link to any 3D engine which can be ported to another environment as well?

Comment: I am currently using MonoGame, hoping to port my games to another platform as well.